# What are end() iterators in a set data structure supposed to return?

Tags: c++, iterator, set

This is indeed Programming HW, but I'm not asking for a code, but rather what am i suppose to be returning when i call iterator function end()? The max value/Right-Most set node?

I believe for begin(), we just get the iterator for root, right, since it is the first thing we inputted.

Also for the operator++ in this Set Data Structure iterators, We just going to increment the iterators depending on the traversal of trees starting from root?

Thank for helping.

Comment: Well, what value will `begin()` have after you call `++` on it enough times?

Comment: it returns something referencing an element "one past the end" of the structure. So if an iterator equals this `end()` element, it is invalid

Comment: The `begin()` for `std::set` returns an iterator to the smallest element, rather than the root, and `++it` points to the successor of that element.

Comment: @JoshG79: The iterator is **not** invalid, it cannot be dereferenced, but it is a **valid** iterator.

Comment: So basically, C.R., begin() start off at the left most node(Since that will be the smallest value), then using the ++operators to traverse the tree accordingly to end of the tree and go pass the last node iterator to get to the end(Which is right after the largest known value)?  So the node structure will retain a data member "parent" so it can go back up the tree to traverse easier. Once it reach the null parent, that would assume it is the root and go find the one pass max value? But I noticed at c++ reference site, these operations should be O(1). So, I must be wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally `end()` returns one-past the end of a structure. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to traverse the entire structure with a `current != end()` loop. This is the case for a std::vector, however iterators are more complex for more complex data structures. But you should always be able to get to `end()` by using `operator++` on the iterator that points to the final element in your iterable structure.

You can not dereference the `end()` element, that is typically undefined behaviour.

Comment: A requirement that is missing in this answer is that you need to be able to get to the last node in the in-order transversal by decrementing the `end()` iterator. This is important as it rules out the use of an iterator holding a null pointer instead of a pointer to a real node.

Comment: Only if it conforms to being a reverse iterator :) - For a random access iterator you need to be able to do all of the above with operator+= and operator-= too. But yes

Comment: For a *set data structure* the iterators would most probably be bidirectional (not *reverse*)

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing the data structure yourself, you can decide what `end()` means. It has to be an iterator of the correct type, and a value that you can match with the result of incrementing a normal iterator beyond the last element in the set. Because iterators into sets are bidirectional, the specific value that you return needs to be able to walk to the previous value in the set.

A common approach is to use a sentry node in the container that holds the pointers to the first and last elements in the data structure, and use an iterator into that node (that does not hold a proper value) as the `end()` iterator.

In the case of `begin()`, it does not represent the value at the root of the tree, but rather the smallest value, so it will be the leftmost node in the tree.